# How to fine tune using XGboost

Tags: python, data-science, xgboost, hyperparameters, overfitting-underfitting

I'm trying to get a generalized model for the Mercedes Greener Manufacturing dataset. So, I'm trying to achieve the same using XGBoost Regressor. I have used a loop ranging from 1-100 as the seed of the train test set so as to get better sampling. I have used PCA to reduce the dimensions to 8 .

How to fine-tune using xgboost so that i don't get a overfitting model?

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_pc,
                                                     y,
                                                     test_size=0.2,
                                                   random_state = i)
    model = XGBRegressor()
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    
    train=model.score(X_train,y_train)
    test=model.score(X_test,y_test)
```

output

```
TEST: 0.28278595203767265 TRAIN: 0.9041892366322192 RS: 0
TEST: 0.3803514386218507 TRAIN: 0.9099759411069458 RS: 1
TEST: 0.3357132066270113 TRAIN: 0.9113739827130357 RS: 2
TEST: 0.3003256802391573 TRAIN: 0.901560899846001 RS: 3
TEST: 0.3769044561739856 TRAIN: 0.9034886060173257 RS: 4
TEST: 0.3449160536081909 TRAIN: 0.9092295020552124 RS: 5
TEST: 0.43083817087609166 TRAIN: 0.8957931397175393 RS: 6
TEST: 0.27375366705147564 TRAIN: 0.912349291318306 RS: 7
TEST: 0.39315883169376264 TRAIN: 0.9090768492254802 RS: 8
TEST: 0.38714220182913905 TRAIN: 0.9089864030990132 RS: 9
TEST: 0.37089065589124093 TRAIN: 0.9099379400411342 RS: 10
TEST: 0.3785854487827084 TRAIN: 0.9080405667805768 RS: 11
TEST: 0.29249852154319345 TRAIN: 0.9057747080596891 RS: 12
TEST: 0.34881642748048425 TRAIN: 0.9077565004654295 RS: 13
```

Answer (score 0):

The `random_state` argument is for ensuring reproducibility on the splits, so that someone else running your experiments can recreate your results.

There are a number of ways to effectively train a model and reduce the chances of overfitting. One such strategy is to use [Cross Fold Validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) along with [Grid Search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to determine the best parameters for your model. Here's how that would look with your model.

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold


X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_pc, y, test_size=0.2)
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()

# Define the parameter options for the Grid Search
paramters = {}

# Define the GridSearch class, including cross-validation, using your XGBoost model
clf = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, parameters, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_folds=5, shuffle=True).split(X_train, y_train))

# Fit the model
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

To retrieve the resulting best estimator, e.g the version of the XGBoost that performed the best during training, you can do the following:

```
best_estimator = clf.best_estimator_
```